# Sencha Touch Navigation View - Changing Title does not work on Back Button

Tags: extjs, navigation, sencha-touch, back

I have a Tab Panel as my initial item inside a Navigation View. When I change tab, I'm updating the Title in the Navigation Bar via:

```
activeitemchange: function(container){
    var navigationView = container.up('navigationview'),
        navigationBar = navigationView.getNavigationBar(),
        newTabTitle = value.tab._title;


    navigationBar.setTitle(newTabTitle);
}
```

The problem is that when I push a new view onto the Navigation View, the Text for the Back Button uses the old/original Title, and not the updated Title. Clicking the Back Button also sets the Navigation View Title to the old/original Title.

The closest I got to finding a solution was this:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?189284-Navigation-View-Title-(IPad-App)

But I get an 'undefined' error on the navigationBar.refreshProxy() call, so I'm assuming that only works for an older version of ST.

Any help would be great,
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you found any answer for this question or solved it by your own since question is quite old. But I tried what you wanted to do and I managed to get the result successfully. So here's the code. I'm following MVC strictly so posting necessary files that need this to work. Basically, views and controllers.

**Main.js** containing TabPanel

```
Ext.define('SO.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.Video'
],
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Welcome',
            iconCls: 'home',

            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

            html: [
                "You've just generated a new Sencha Touch 2 project. What you're looking at right now is the ",
            ].join("")
        },
        {
            title: 'Get Started',
            iconCls: 'action',

            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Push a new view!',
                    action:'push_new_view'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

});

**Nav.js** having navigation view and default item as above tab panel

```
Ext.define('SO.view.Nav', {
extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
xtype: 'nav',
config:{
    fullscreen: true,

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Default View',
            xtype:'main'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

And finally, controller. I did every user interaction handling in controller itself.

```
Ext.define('SO.controller.Nav',{
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
    config:{
        refs:{
            views:['SO.view.Main','SO.view.Nav'],
            navView:'nav',
            tabView:'main'
        },
        control:{
            tabView:{
                activeitemchange:'changeTitle'
            },
            'button[action=push_new_view]':{
                tap:'pushNewView'
            }
        }
    },
    changeTitle:function(container,value,oldValue,eOpts ){
        console.log(value.title);
        this.getNavView().getNavigationBar().setTitle(value.title);
    },
    pushNewView:function(){
        var activeTabTitle = this.getTabView().getActiveItem().title;
        var controller = this;
        controller.getNavView().push({
            title: 'Second',
            html: 'Second view!'
        });
        controller.getNavView().getNavigationBar().getBackButton().setText(activeTabTitle);
        controller.getNavView().getNavigationBar().getBackButton().on('tap',function(self){             
            controller.getNavView().getNavigationBar().setTitle(activeTabTitle);
        });
    }
}
```

);

As you can see, I've attached function that changes title according to selected tab in `changeTitle` function.

the function `pushNewView` pushes new view and let's you ovverride back button behavior on tap. What I did is simply, get `activeItem()` from tab panel which holds a button that pushes new view. Once we got activeItem we can get it's title and that title need to be set to `backButtnoText`. So I traverse navigation view and getBackButton instance and simply by calling `setText()` method changed back button text.

Same time, I've attached event handler to back button, as we do want to change navigation bar title to previous title. So once, use taps back button, we set back the title to title we got in above step. You might want to detach event handler once you're done with eveything as it might cause problems or I'd rather say it'd be good.

Just try this, it just works.

Comment: Excellent, I got this to work. The only difference is that I had to use "value.tab.getTitle()" instead of "value.title" - any idea why? I am using version 2.1.0

Comment: @Brett well, i'm also using 2.1 and both gave me same results. Are you getting error when `value.title` is used ?

Comment: `value.title` and `value.tab.title` both return `undefined` - no error. It's no big deal; just curious. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the title of the parent viewport, not just to the navigation view tile. Basically the Navigation title is already changing by itself based on the parent view **title**, and all pushed component **title**.

```
var view = Ext.create('Ext.NavigationView', {
    fullscreen: true,

    items: [{
        title: 'Change this title ',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Push a new view!',
            handler: function() {
                view.push({
                    title: 'Second Title',
                    html: 'Second view!'
                });
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

It should look something like this:

```
activeitemchange: function(container){
    var newTabTitle = value.tab._title;
    container.setTitle(newTabTitle);
}
```

Comment: The title works fine when I push a new view - it is when I change the active tab (inside the navigation view) and dynamically set the Navigation Bar's Title where I am experiencing this issue.

Comment: You could add a wrap "container" component for to Tabpanel, and change title of the Navigation bar and in the same time for the container title as well, and it will have the new title. Or cache this "var" with new tile and set 1 more time on back event, i I understood it right

Comment: I'm not quite following you. Could you edit your answer with some example code? Thanks for your time. Just so I'm clear, I can successfully change the Title in the Navigation View. It's when I push a new view when I have a problem - the text of the Back Button is showing the old Title, not the Title I've just set.

Comment: if you can post you structure I can try to help you with

Answer (score 0):

```
//viewAppt is the reference of the view 
//Use this 
viewAppts.query('#headerTitlebar')[0].setTitle('Title');
// Instead of this
this.getApptsHeaderTitlebar().setTitle('Title');
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.